# Process has died

Tags: android

In my app i am downloading images from the web. Sometimes i am getting the following error in stack trace and then app crashed. What is meaning of the "process has died"? How to handle this?

```
ERROR
09-06 11:03:46.127 I/ActivityManager(   98): Process com.ibkr.elgifto (pid 7684) has died.
09-06 11:03:46.157 I/WindowManager(   98): WIN DEATH: Window{44b0e778 com.ibkr.elgifto/com.ibkr.elgifto.ElgiftoSplash paused=false}
09-06 11:03:46.167 I/WindowManager(   98): WIN DEATH: Window{44b4e400 com.ibkr.elgifto/com.ibkr.elgifto.Ehome paused=false}
09-06 11:03:46.207 I/ActivityManager(   98): Start proc com.ibkr.elgifto for activity com.ibkr.elgifto/.ElgiftoSplash: pid=8011 uid=10060 gids={3003, 1015}
09-06 11:03:46.487 I/UsageStats(   98): Unexpected resume of com.ibkr.elgifto while already resumed in com.ibkr.elgifto
09-06 11:04:16.687 W/InputManagerService(   98): Got RemoteException sending 'screen on/off' notification to pid 7684 uid 10060
```

Comment: I get a similar problem after an activity has finished calling a background service to copy a file.. +1 in search of solution..

Comment: Can you paste some code please ? The activity code in particular ? that logcat dump doesn't say much..

Answer (score 2):

By the stack trace I underatand that your app is resumed while its already running. Wich causes your process to be killed and start again.

Check to see if you are downloading the image on the main thread. If u do that might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The way you handle this through handlers and background service and different threads.

Make sure that you dont do any network operations in UI thread